# How should I randomise order of files selected in my directory?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a directory of files of which I want the files to be selected in a random order. I am wondering what the best way to do this is – I am thinking some sort of use of 'Arrange by: Date Modified' then using some basic bash(?) touch to change these dates in a random order. How would I code a random-file-toucher? Is there a better way? What would it be?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shuf` command to randomize your input:

```
cd /path/to/my/folder
shuf -e *
```

Comment: How do you do combine this with touch?

Comment: @MikeBrown Why do you want to touch the files?

Comment: I want to be able to select them in a random order

Comment: @MikeBrown `touch` is not a command to _select_ files. It only updates the timestamp file. I don't understand your use case, please describe it better in your question.

Comment: I mentioned I want a way to be able to select files in a random order. I mention touch and arrange by date modified as a possible way of doing this, but I'm unsure how to do so. How can shuf be made helpful in this case?

Answer (score 2):

```
shuf -e * | head -10
```

Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by 'select'? do you mean you just want to select some of them of the directory? 
I don't have reputation to comment, thus I wrote here, @oliv 's answer is good enough to me